# Error: The studio server does not have access to listen to given port do you have access to listen to the given host (localhost)? on macbook sanity

Tags: reactjs, backend, content-management-system, sanity

Error: The studio server does not have access to listen to given port do you have access to listen to the given host (localhost)? on macbook sanity  project

Error: The studio server does not have access to listen to given port do you have access to listen to the given host (localhost)? on macbook sanity

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This issue has been resolved i run the command with sudo npm run dev